# PHP File Upload not working with $_FILES variable it is always undefined

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload, upload

Ok I have a page where a user uploads a file that looks like this:

Upload.php:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />       
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />     
</form>
```

upload_file.php:

```
<?php   
$target = "upload/";    
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;   
$ok=1;    
$uploaded_type= $_FILES['uploaded']['type'];  
$uploaded_size= $_FILES['uploaded']['size'];  

//This is our size condition   
if ($uploaded_size > 350000)    
{    
echo "Your file is too large.<br>";    
$ok=0;   
}   

//This is our limit file type condition   
if ($uploaded_type =="text/php")    
{     
echo "No PHP files<br>";     
$ok=0;     
}     

//Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error      
if ($ok==0)       
{       
Echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded";      
}      

//If everything is ok we try to upload it      
else       
{       
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))       
{      
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";      
}      
else     
{     
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";     
}     
}      
?>
```

Whenever I test it the webpage just returns this

**Notice :**  Undefined index: uploaded in **\htdocs\upload_file.php** on line 3
**Notice :**  Undefined variable: uploaded_size in **\htdocs\upload_file.php** on line 7
**Notice :**  Undefined variable: uploaded_type in **\htdocs\upload_file.php** on line 14
**Notice :** Undefined index: uploaded in **A:\xampp\htdocs\upload_file.php** on line 29

Can Someone please tell me what I did wrong here. Sorry if Its a very simple fix.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: change php error level to error

Comment: You have `$_FILES['uploaded']` at the top, but `$_FILES['uploadedfile']` lower? Which one is correct. Also, only the first notice line lines up. Is this your actual code?

Comment: first; put in a check if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded']) {..code to work with it here...} else { ...no uploded file...}  This clears up the structure a bit

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here. Lots of small novice programmer stuff, but I did some cleanup.  The most egregious issue is the basic formatting which made things hard to read.  So I cleaned that up. Also, I set a check at the beginning of the script that will do a very basic check to see if `$_FILES['uploaded']` is even set. Also, you have a variable called `$ok` you are using to do basic `TRUE`/`FALSE` checks.  I adjusted that to be actual `TRUE`/`FALSE` values.

Also, your line that reads:

```
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
```

Makes no sense since the rest of the script refers to `$_FILES['uploaded']`.  So I corrected that as well.

Now past all of that, what shows up when you do a basic variable dump in the script like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '<pre>';
```

That will show you what is actually in the `$_FILES` array to make debugging easier.  Heck, I added that to the script with a basic `TRUE`/`FALSE` switch to allow you to quickly switch it on & off when needed.

```
<?php

if (TRUE) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($_FILES);
  echo '<pre>';
}

$ok = TRUE;    

// Check if there is an uploaded file.
if (!array_key_exists('uploaded', $_FILES) && !empty($_FILES['uploaded'])) {
  echo "Sorry, no file seems to be uploaded.";
  $ok = FALSE; 
}

$target = "upload/";    
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;   
$uploaded_type = $_FILES['uploaded']['type'];  
$uploaded_size = $_FILES['uploaded']['size'];  

// This is our size condition.  
if ($uploaded_size > 350000) {    
  echo "Your file is too large.<br>";    
  $ok = FALSE;   
}   

//This is our limit file type condition   
if ($uploaded_type =="text/php") {     
  echo "No PHP files<br>";     
  $ok = FALSE;     
}     

// Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error      
if ($ok) {       
  echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded";      
}
// If everything is ok we try to upload it      
else {       
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) {      
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded";      
  }      
  else {     
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";     
  }     
}      
?>
```

Comment: I still get errors undefined index: uploaded on lines 17, 18, 19

Comment: Is it something im doing wrong @JakeGould? I set my phpINI's to the correct sizes 8M and 2M and its set to on